# disable mysql innodb stopwords for a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I would like to disable the stopwords for a full text index. The database is running innodb on mysql 5.6.

I would like to disable it for one table only. I found the mysql docs for innodb_ft_user_stopword_table but I'm confused about how to make my index use this table. I'm assuming I could simply create an empty table to disable this feature.

The fulltext index currently exists and is respecting stopwords.

I'm thinking the process should be something like:

1. create empty stopword table
2. some how point the index to the new stopword table
3. re-build the index (or delete and re-create in which case do step 2 here.)

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: shortest way would be to update `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and then set `ft_stopword_file = ""` and then restart mysql `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` and finally repair the table `repair table table_name`

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify on BK435's answer, you don't set the table to the innodb_ft_enable_stopword variable, you enable it and then set it to the innodb_ft_server_stopword_table or innodb_ft_user_stopword_table:

```
innodb_ft_enable_stopword=1
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table=db_name/table_name
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table=db_name/table_name
```

For the user stopword table, I don't see in the documentation where you specify WHAT table you are effecting... it says that it's per table but doesn't specify exactly how you do it...

I wrote up a little more detail on this post:

[MySQL 5.6 Full Text Search Issue when Searching for the word "the" in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420702/mysql-5-6-full-text-search-issue-when-searching-for-the-word-the-in-php/33491946#33491946)

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble trying to set up a custom stopwords table as well and in my case, the issue was that I was using:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_ft_user_stopword_table = 'database/table';
```

instead of

```
SET SESSION innodb_ft_user_stopword_table = 'database/table';
```

Here are all the steps:

1. Delete the old index if it exists.

```
ALTER TABLE `database`.`table` DROP INDEX `idx_table_column_search`;
```

2. Create a custom stopword table:

```
CREATE TABLE `database`.`table_stopword`(value VARCHAR(30)) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

3. [Optional] Insert words

```
INSERT INTO table_stopword(value) VALUES ('myword');
```

4. Set variables only on session scope to be used only for the current table/index

```
SET SESSION innodb_ft_enable_stopword = 1;
SET SESSION innodb_ft_user_stopword_table = 'database/table_stopword';
```

5. Create the index

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_table_column_search ON database.table(column);
```

6. Set the qualified name of an InnoDB table containing a FULLTEXT index

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_ft_aux_table='database/table';
```

7. Check the configurations

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_FT_CONFIG;
```

| KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| optimize_checkpoint_limit | 180 |
| synced_doc_id | 14 |
| stopword_table_name | database/table_stopword |
| use_stopword | 1 |

8. See words in the index

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html)

> innodb_ft_enable_stopword
>
> Specifies that a set of stopwords is associated with an InnoDB FULLTEXT index at the time the index is created. If the innodb_ft_user_stopword_table option is set, the stopwords are taken from that table. Else, if the innodb_ft_server_stopword_table option is set, the stopwords are taken from that table. Otherwise, a built-in set of default stopwords is used.

Your step 1 is correct. In step 2, you would need to set the parameter `innodb_ft_enable_stopword = yournewtableofwords` in your my.cnf file, and then reboot mysql for the change to take affect.  In step 3, you are correct, both options seem acceptable. You can update the statistics or drop and recreate the index. You may want to consider the latter and not the former just to be sure.

You may also find this link [Here](https://mariadb.com/blog/mysql-56-innodb-fulltext-round-2-stopwords) from MariaDB's website on stopwords with fulltext index's useful too.