# MySQL 5.6 Full Text Search Issue when Searching for the word "the" in PHP

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

Im having an issue when my search includes the word "the" in my full text search.

Here is my search code with the problem:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE MATCH(myname) AGAINST ('+the' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This one works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE MATCH(myname) AGAINST ('+and' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I already turned off the stop words in my CNF file, changed the min letters to 3 using both `ft_min_word_len=3` AND `innodb_ft_min_token_size=3`

I'm using innodb. And returns 27000 results and 'the' returns 17000 from a db of about 500,000 records so im not hitting the 50% mark, even so, I'm using boolean mode. I can't find another word that breaks this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I finally figured this out. It looks like I already had the myisam stopwords cleared but not the innodb ones. It's a little but harder to do than for myisam but here are the steps for anyone else that might need it:

In your /etc/my.cnf (or my.ini on windows) add these lines:

Create a stopwords table. I made mine in a db called `settings` and a table called `innodb-stopwords`. You cannot just set `innodb_ft_enable_stopword = 0`, you have to create and link to a table.

Make sure your table is innodb and add a column called `value`, varchar(?), utf8_general_ci. You can leave it empty or add values to the table.

```
innodb_ft_enable_stopword = 1  
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table = settings/innodb-stopwords
```

Restart your mysql server.

Drop and recreate your fulltext indexes.

If you don't want to restart the server, you can dynamically set the variables with (also update the cnf/ini file for the next server restart)

```
--innodb_ft_enable_stopword=1
--innodb_ft_server_stopword_table=db_name/table_name
```

I don't see any workaround to recreating the index... you can do it in one command though so the table is locked the whole time and your users don't get errors:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` DROP INDEX indexname, ADD FULLTEXT(`columnname`);
```

Comment: (It's OK to Accept your own Answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Build a different stop-word list.  Remove "the" and "and" from it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have ft_stopword_file = "" in my.cnf and restarted the server. I've had this setup for months now and have confirmed it's set properly. As I was saying in my post, the word 'and' works, I'm just having trouble with the word 'the'...